# Using formik custom validation to check data in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, validation, formik

Task:

In my application I want to enter a username that already exists in my database and get a red error in the form field such as 'username must be unique.

Is it possible to write some some custom validation to ensure formik checks the MySQL database first, to see if this username exists in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Catch this exact error and then process it as a duplicate attempt.

Attempting to catch it up front will only result in a race condition, where when raced, will just get the same error.